# Perl - Split string on comma. Ignore whitespace

Tags: regex, perl

I have this string:

```
$str="     a, b,    c>d:e,  f,    g ";
```

In this string there might be **spaces** and/or **tabs**

I split the string in perl:

```
my (@COLUMNS) = split(/[\s\t,]+/, $str));
```

But this creates a leading space in position [0].

```
@COLUMNS=[

    a
    b
    c>d:e
    f
    g
]
```

I want this:

```
@COLUMNS=[
    a
    b
    c>d:e
    f
    g
]
```

Comment: Just a sidenote: you don't no need to explicitely state the `\t` because `\s` already includes both spaces and tabs (and every other _whitespace character_ although I don't know others).

Comment: @PerlDog: The Unicode names of the ASCII characters matched by `\s` are `CHARACTER TABULATION`, `LINE FEED`, `LINE TABULATION`, `FORM FEED`, `CARRIAGE RETURN`, and `SPACE`. That is `[\t\n\x0B\f\r ]`. There are a dozen or more characters outside ASCII that also match

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest that you use a global regex match to find all subsequences of characters that are neither commas nor whitespace

It will produce the same output as your `split(/[\s\t,]+/`. (Note that the `\t` is superfluous because `\s` also matches tabs.) But will create a list without any empty elements

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my $str = "     a, b,    c>d:e,  f,    g ";

my @columns = $str =~ /[^\s,]+/g;

use Data::Dump;
dd \@columns;
```

#### output

```
["a", "b", "c>d:e", "f", "g"]
```

***Note that***, just like your split, this method will ignore any empty fields: something like `a,,,b` will return `[ 'a', 'b' ]` instead of `[ 'a', '', '', 'b' ]`. Also, columns that contain whitespace will be split, so `a,two words,b` will produce `[ 'a', 'two', 'words', 'b' ]` instead of `[ 'a', 'two words', 'b' ]`. Only you can tell whether these situations are likely to arise

If there is any chance that this method will produce the wrong results, then it is better to simply split on commas and write a subroutine to trim the resulting fields

```perl
use strict; 
use warnings 'all';

sub trim(;$);

my $str="     a  ,, ,two words ,,, b";
my @columns = map trim, split /,/, $str;

use Data::Dump;
dd \@columns;


sub trim(;$) {
    (my $trimmed = $_[0] // $_) =~ s/\A\s+|\s+\z//g;
    $trimmed;
}
```

#### output

```
["a", "", "", "two words", "", "", "b"]
```

Comment: None of these work for me, the first one returns `["    ",  ",    ", ",    ", ",    "]` etc.

Comment: Have you copied the code directly from my answer? It's fairly basic Perl that hasn't changed since v5.8

Comment: Ugh! I forgot to add the `^` before `\s`. This is much cleaner code than the answer I accepted first. I will use this instead, thank you very much!

Answer (score 7):

A pretty common solution to this is to transform the values returned from split. In this case you want to remove any leading or trailing space, normally called a *trim* operation. Using this approach you don't have to worry about spaces at all in the split operation:

```
use strict; 
use warnings; 

my $str="     a, b,    c>d:e,  f,    g ";
my @columns = map { s/^\s*|\s*$//gr } split(/,/, $str);
print join(',', @columns), "\n";
```

Another solution as @toolic mentions above is to remove all spaces beforehand:

```
use strict; 
use warnings; 

my $str="     a, b,    c>d:e,  f,    g ";
$str =~ s/\s+//g; # remove all occurrences of 1 or more spaces
my @columns = split(/,/, $str);
print join(',', @columns), "\n";
```

both of the above solutions return this output:

> a,b,c>d:e,f,g

More information about the [`/r`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) modifier:

`/r` is a modifier that can be applied to substitutions that is non-destructive. Meaning that the original string is not modified, instead a copy is created, modified, and returned. This has advantages because normally in scalar context the `s///` operator will return the number of substitutions that occurred instead of the modified string. This is only available in Perl versions >= 5.14. An equivalent statement for Perl versions below this would be:

```
my $original = "some_string";
(my $copy = $original) =~ s/$search_pattern/$replace_pattern/;
```

and to use in a map:

```
map { 
   (my $temp = $_) =~ s/$search_pattern/$replace_pattern/; $temp 
} split /$delimiter/, $original;
```

ex:

```
my $string = 'abc'; 
my $num_substitutions = $string =~ s/a/d/; # 1 

my $string = 'abc';
my $new_string = $string =~ s/a/d/r; # dbc
```

Comment: map { s/^\s*|\s*$//gr } "r" means could you please in detail?

Comment: `my @columns = map { s/^\s*|\s*$//gr } split(/,/, $str);` worked perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Note `r` regex modifier is only available in versions of perl >  5.14